# Was the creation of the little red haired girl inspired by a childhood crush?

Tags: character, charlie-brown

In Charlie Brown, was the creation of "The Little Red Haired Girl" inspired by a Charles Schulz' childhood crush?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a Wikipedia article on the [little red-haired girl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Red-Haired_Girl), it was actually an adulthood crush of Schulz's:

> A former coworker, Donna Mae Johnson (born circa 1929 in Minneapolis,
>   Minnesota), was Schulz's inspiration for the character. A 1947 high
>   school graduate, Johnson was working in the accounting department of
>   the Art Instruction, Inc., a correspondence school where Schulz
>   worked. Johnson and Schulz eventually became romantically involved and
>   dated for three years, but in 1950 when Schulz proposed to her, she
>   turned him down, saying she was already engaged to fireman Allan Wold.
>   She married Allan on October 21, 1950. Schulz was devastated, but he
>   and Johnson-Wold remained friends for the rest of his life.